# Using cin with arrays

Tags: c++, cin

I'm trying to get user input for two arrays. I'm getting the error no operator matches these operands. Why isn't my cin function working?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string canadates[5];
    int votes[5];
    double percent[5];
    int i;
    while (i <= 5) {
        cin<< canadates << votes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's quite a few issues with your code.

First, `cin` uses different operator than `cout`.

```
cin >> canadates >> votes;
```

Second, also part of the compiler error - you cannot read into whole array. You need into read into *single element* of an array. How do you access single array element?

```
cin >> canadates[i] >> votes[i];
```

Third, your loop is infinite one, because `i` never changes.

```
while (i <= 5) {
    cin >> canadates[i] >> votes[i];
    i++;
}
```

Fourth, `i` is unitialized - it has indeterminate value. Always initialize your variables.

```
int i = 0;
while (i <= 5) {
    cin >> canadates[i] >> votes[i];
    i++;
}
```

Fifth, arrays in C++ use zero-based indexing, which means first possible index is `0` and last possible index is `arraySize - 1`. Accessing element `5` in array of `5` elements is wrong.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
    cin >> canadates[i] >> votes[i];
    i++;
}
```

---

Points 3 and 4 are much easier to avoid if you use `for` loop. It's syntax makes you remember about all those little things.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cin >> canadates[i] >> votes[i];
}
```

See? Both issues solved in one line, and you need 3 statements there, compiler will check that (but compiler will not prevent you from shooting your own foot - each of the 3 statements may be empty, or you may still use them wrongly). And if you make a mental rule that `i <= something` is highly suspicious, you can also avoid 5th easier.

---

I don't want to discourage you from programming, but C++ is a difficult language. You will not be able to learn it without [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)/tutor, and in particular the fact that "code looks reasonable" or "code compiles" means nothing here.